# How to modify archive query with pre_get_posts to append CPTs?

Tags: custom-post-types, query, archives, pre-get-posts

If I use `pre_get_posts` this way

```
function ef_company_query($query) {
  if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_post_type_archive( 'company' ) ) {
    $query->set('post_type', array( 'company', 'mission', 'values', 'staff' ) );
  }
}

add_action('pre_get_posts','ef_company_query');
```

it seems that wordpress won't load archive-company.php but archive.php.

How should I use `pre_get_posts` to append extra CPTs to an archive page?

**EDIT 1**

I mentioned archive-company.php because I want to load the extra CPTs at URL www.website.com/company.

**EDIT 2**

I'm open to any solution which pulls a specific template based on the URL www.website.com/company and allows the addition of the extra CPTs (preferably via `pre_get_posts`, performance wise).

**EDIT 3**

Trying to make things more clear here!

I want to be able to load several CPTs on the URL www.website.com/company.

1. Which template should/can I use?
2. How to append the CPTs to the main query (hopefully via `pre_get_posts`, performance wise)?

I'm trying to avoid the use of `new WP_Query()` and having multiple loops in the page.

Answer (score 1):

You seems to assume that it would grab archive for *first* of multiple post types. But why? Order in this case does not indicate any kind of priority.

WP seems to consider that logical as well. If you take a look at `get_archive_template()` the individual template will only be considered if there is *only one* post type in query.

Multiple post types in query will cause `archive.php` to load, as you are observing.

If you want to load more specific template, you would need to override that via filters as well, for example with `archive_template` one (dynamic one in `get_query_template()`).

Comment: I wasn't assuming that actually!
The reason why I mentioned archive-company.php is because I want to load those extra CPTs at www.website.com/company/.

Comment: Well, then it's not clear what template has to do with your question. URL and template are not _directly_ connected. Template depends on query which depends on URL.

Comment: I've already updated my question. I would be glad for any solution which pulls a template dependent on the URL www.website.com/company/ and allows the query to add the extra CPTs.

Comment: Adding CPTs to query you already seem to have. Customizing template of result is covered in my answer. You might want to try to rephrase your question as what you _expect_ result of your code to be exactly and what _actually_ happens.

Comment: I've looked into `get_query_template` but couldn't find any hint on how they could help me with my issue. As far as I could understand `get_query_template` will only retrieve the path of the archive template…

Comment: @DiogoBento yes, it will receive `archive.php` for reasons described in answer. You can use filter to _change_ that to a template you want.